# Build PHP on windows, issuewith bison

Tags: php, build, bison, m4

Well I am trying to build PHP on windows, and I've followed this guide almost perfectly so far, until I ran into a weird error I have no idea how to fix:
https://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/stepbystepbuild

> Error: cannot open file c:/progra~1/bison/share/bison/m4sugar/m4sugar.m4: No such file or directory 
>   nmake: fatal error U1077: D:\Development\Microsoft Visual Studio\VC\Bin\amd64\bison.exe: return code '0x1'

What does error message mean? and how can I fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Did you install bison yourself, or was it automatically installed for you?

I notice that bison appears to be installed in the path `C:\Program Files\bison\`. If this is indeed the case it would explain the failure. Bison and Flex cannot be installed in a path containing a space, otherwise they fail in the way you have seen. The issue is mentioned in the instructions for installing bison on windows.

The solution is to uninstall bison and re-install correctly and then try the build again.